# C# passing multiple form fields to the other form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form1 where i can order items by using `numericUpDown`.
[image]

I want to get all the items, retail price, and sub total of all items that is chosen by the user including the total.

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form1 = new Form1();

    for (int i=1; i<=15; i++)
    {
        if(form1.num[i].Value != 0)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

how can i take all the values here and use it in my form2? here is my form2

[image]

Comment: If you _dynamically_ build that list somehow (you do not place each control with designer but you build such repetitive UI using a generic method) then it's easier. If not you have to use some naming convention to retrieve every control given its name and building a list of Product (use a class). Note that you don't need to forward everything, just number and retail price...everything else may be calculated in your second form. From UX point of view: do you even need such second form?

Comment: yes I need that second form as it makes my application look cleaner and user friendly. I understand your point but can you be more specific on what i am suppose to do to get the values because im fairly new to c#

Comment: Separate the view from the data, you need a `List<Product>`.  Your Form2 class must *not* create a new instance of Form1, that's pointless, pass the List to its constructor.

Comment: Just a sidenode to your "look cleaner and user friendly": from my experience, the users generally don't really like these pop-up forms

Comment: is it better if i condense them into one form? @xeraphim

Comment: there are many alternatives... take a look at this for an example of a wizard: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/56211/alternatives-for-multiple-popup-dialogs-that-look-the-same-and-are-frequently-us

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this list comes from some kind of data query, I would suggest putting the values into some kind of array, where each element stores the "ID" for the item, items display name, and the selected amount.

When clicking the button that would show this second form, iterate through the controls displayed and record the value in the Numeric Up/Down control for each item, then pass that array as a argument to the contructor of the second form.

The second form should then build its display based on the values from the array.  You could, then, only display items with an "amount" > 0.

Comment: i like the idea of array. but can i do this without using a database?

Comment: Sure you could.  It would just be a matter of populating the array in code, rather than reading data from a database.

Answer (score 1):

As @AdrianoRepetti sad, this isn't the best approach to create application. You should create class called Products with properties: Name,Category,Price,Quantity...
You should store data in database or different data store like XML, then you can fetch data from data source, and bind data to list of products and show data in grid view control. Here is simple example http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial

In form2 constructor you can pass List of Products, and iterate over the list to calculate SubTotal

Answer (score 0):

You should store first form data in data base and in next form load you can easily fetch them from data base and fill the grid view.
If you have any problem to use data base or design tables ask me please.